# Apache Reverse Proxy Error

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

My web system:

Internet<--->Apache Reverse Proxy<---->Apache Application Server

URL for client access internet: www.example.com

My problem:

When I access www.example.com and upload data(this is excel file). I get the following error:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST
>   /index.php/adminstrator/store/substore/import/.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.example.com Port 80

To resolve the problem I have set the configuration in httpd.conf:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequest 0
KeepAliveTimeout 7200
```

But it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved similar errors by setting the following in the httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled
```

This seems to be a bug with Apache 2.2.x I believe.

Hope this helps someone.